# Change the colors of TwoLineAvatarIconListItem in kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

```
               TwoLineAvatarIconListItem:

                    on_release:
                        screen_manager.current = "screen1"

                    text: "DinoDevonioz"
                    secondary_text: "Secondary text here"

                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon: "woman.jpg"

                    IconRightWidget:
                        icon: "minus"
                    
                    text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
```

Is not working. Id like to change the color for each line of text in this widget. How do i do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
    TwoLineAvatarIconList:
        text: 'Your text'
        text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        secondary_text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
```

Read the docs: https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/list/#twolineavatarlistitem